SOLR: filter by number of values in multivalued pdate field matching criterium
When using field:
<field name="importantDays" type="pdate" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" docValues="true"/>
I'd like to filter documents using standard date range filter syntax [2024-8-10 TO 2024-8-24] and also based on how many dates are stored in the desired time range in the same document. For example,
Doc A: importantDays:[2024-08-10T00:00:00Z, 2024-08-11T00:00:00Z, 2024-08-12T00:00:00Z, 2024-08-13T00:00:00Z, 2024-08-29T00:00:00Z]

Doc B: importantDays:[2024-08-10T00:00:00Z, 2024-08-11T00:00:00Z, 2024-08-29T00:00:00Z]

I am only interested in documents in [2024-8-10 TO 2024-8-14] range that have 3 or more dates stored in that range. Doc A passes this criterium, Doc B does not. Is it possible to create such filter query using solr? Faceting on results set is mandatory.
I found one q&a that tries to address this issue from 13 years ago here: Solr: Filtering on the number of matches in an OR query to a multivalued field
It uses sum, frange and termfreq. I think the corresponding search query using frange and termfreq would be:
"fq":[
 "importantDays:["2024-08-10T00:00:00Z" TO "2024-08-14T00:00:00Z"]",

 "{!frange l=3}sum(
       termfreq(importantDays,"2024-08-10T00:00:00Z"),
       termfreq(importantDays,"2024-08-11T00:00:00Z"),
       termfreq(importantDays,"2024-08-12T00:00:00Z"),
       termfreq(importantDays,"2024-08-13T00:00:00Z")
     )"
]

This filter query returns zero results. It seem that termfreq is not working as intended when working with pdate values. Any idea on how to perform the above described query?
